# How do I use captions with GTLYouTubeVideoContentDetails and GTLYouTubeVideo?

Tags: objective-c, google-api-objc-client

I have successfully implemented YouTube video upload. Since I am also dealing with text that can be used as subtitles, I'd like to upload these, as well.

`GTLYouTubeVideoContentDetails`’s header does not mention what format "caption" has to be in, so I tried SRT, but that didn't work. The SRT file itself seems to be valid, I uploaded it manually to a demo video and it looked fine.

My approach was this:

```
GTLYouTubeVideo *video = [GTLYouTubeVideo object];
if (nil != captionString)
{
    GTLYouTubeVideoContentDetails *details = [[GTLYouTubeVideoContentDetails alloc] init];
    details.caption = captionString;
    video.contentDetails = details;
    [details release];
}
```

This was the only alteration to the previously working code. The result now is HTTP status 501 when trying to upload.

Any ideas?